# Why '\n'('\r') does not work in my expect script

Tags: expect

I want to input `y+enter` to reply the question while executing `copy tftp:something`.
The script will send `y`, but `\n` does not work. It will stay `(y/n)y` and keep there without exiting or doing something else. I have tried `\r`, and the result was the same. Does anyone know the reason?

```
#!bin/bash

expect -c "
set timeout -1
spawn telnet x.x.x.x
expect \"username\"
send \"user\n\"
expect \"password\"
send \"pw\n\"
expect \"model\"
send \"copy tftp:something\n\"
expect \"(y/n)\"
send \"y\n\"
expect eof
"
exit 0
```

Answer (score 0):

I prefer using `\r` to "hit enter".

Second, your entire bash script is expect, so remove the outer bash layer.

```tcl
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
set timeout -1
spawn telnet x.x.x.x
expect "username"
send "user\r"
expect "password"
send "pw\r"
expect "model"
send "copy tftp:something\r"
expect "(y/n)"
send "y\r"
expect eof
```

If you have more logic in the bash part, to avoid quoting hell use a heredoc:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
expect <<'END_EXPECT'
    set timeout -1
    spawn telnet x.x.x.x
    expect "username"
    send "user\r"
    expect "password"
    send "pw\r"
    expect "model"
    send "copy tftp:something\r"
    expect "(y/n)"
    send "y\r"
    expect eof
END_EXPECT
exit 0
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Actually I have tried these methods, but none can be effective. I am still confused that `\r` does not work when I send `y\r`.

Comment: I don't understand why. I'd suggest you run with `expect -d` to enable verbose debug output: that might provide some clues.